# How to convert subtitles time to start and stop frame (SRT to SUB) and backwards

Tags: video, converters, avi, subtitle, srt

I want convert SRT subtitles to SUB and backwards. But I don´t know, how to convert time from SRT to start and stop frame from SUB format. Can you help me?

Comment: Try http://konwerternapisow.pl/en/
Start and stop frame calculated from frames/sec, so dont forget to fill that input.

Comment: I find this code for convert from sub to srt http://thecodecracker.com/python/script-to-convert-sub-format-to-srt/ ...but what backwards?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I founded this [solution](http://thecodecracker.com/python/script-to-convert-sub-format-to-srt/) ...I hope this will help someone other

Answer (score 0):

The formula is simple:

Time (in seconds) * FPS (frames per second)(of the video) = {frame}

i.e.:

00:00:00,000 --> 00:00:42,740

Bla bLa blA

calculate:

0*23,976 = 0

42,740*23,976 = 1024

results is:

{0}{1024}Bla bLa blA

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like that:

```
Subtitles::convert('subtitles.srt', 'subtitles.sub');

Subtitles::convert('subtitles.sub', 'subtitles.srt');
```

more info: https://github.com/mantas-done/subtitles